# is returned Doctrine_collection null

Tags: php, collections, symfony1, doctrine, null

i have a very simple question. i searched for it everywhere but i didn't find anything.

i have a Doctrine query like this:

```
return Doctrine_Core::getTable('something')->createQuery()->where('where clause')- 
>execute();
```

i want to check whether it returns something or not. just it. if it's content is null i don't do other stuff. empty doesn't work, isset doesn't work ,count doesn't work . what am i suppose to do?

i know it's so simple but i don't know how to do it.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this return? Please use `var_dump()` on the result and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
return Doctrine_Core::getTable('something')
    ->createQuery()->where('where clause')->count();
```

Comment: yeah it works sometimes . but sometimes when i'm using it in view, it says "undefined method call count on non-object blah blah blah" 
but in this situation (in action) it works fine .
thanks anyway.

Comment: it doesn't work when you are using standard methods created by doctrine. for example Book has a getLessons() method that returns book's lessons. if it doesn't have any lessons you cant use ->count() because the result is not an object. i was wondering if there is a way that works in every situation!

Answer (score 0):

What about executing `->count()` on result array?

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/b0fe08b9b3da3e41/22e036fe4674f619?pli=1

Comment: i don't want to convert it to array. i need objects.

Answer (score 0):

$obj = Doctrine_Core::getTable('something')->createQuery()->where('where clause')->execute();

if ($obj == null)
{
}`enter code here`

else
{
}

Comment: i know it should work this way but i always get a Doctrine_Collection that is not null . it has a record with nothing in it(all of the fields are empty). when i use fetchone it works fine but when using execute it doesn't.